# ARChon Runtime for Chrome Extension - Unable to Install - Version Error

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**How to install the Archon Runtine for Chrome extension without error???**

Try to Install ARChon Runtime for Chrome  from below Link

https://archon-runtime.github.io/

Pls. find below the error screenshot. Even i tried changing my chrome browser Latest Version 99.0.4844.82   in the "manifest" . Even then i am getting the same error. Pls. Help. How to install the Archon Runtine for Chrome extension without error??? Pls. Help

[image: Chrome Extension Link]

[image: ARChon Runtime for Chrome Extension in Chrome Screen with Error Button]

[image: ARChon Runtime for Chrome Extension in Chrome Screen Error Details]

[image: My System Chrome Latest Version]

Comment: Have you tried removing the "minimum_chrome_version" key from the manifest.json? Try to remove that and also the 'arc_build_tag' key